# Can I add predefined jars to WEB-INF/lib in Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, jar, buildpath

When I am designing normal Java project in Eclipse, I can add predefined libraries to it's Build Path. Can I do the same way when putting jars into WEB-INF/lib folder of Web project? I.e. can I ask Eclipse to put some predefined library jars there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy / import a Jar there; it will be added to the build path automatically. You will find it in the package explorer within the `Web App Libraries` (or in the build path in the project properties). The project has to have the Dynamic Web App nature.

Comment: But can I maintain local library of such jars like in Preferences->Java->Build Path->User Libraries?

Comment: Ah, you add a user library and want to publish it to WEB-INF/lib? After you added it to the build path you switch to `Deployment Assembly` in the project properties and add the `Java Build Path Entry` for that user library. For "real" projects I would use Maven which takes care of such things automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I copied the jar files into my WEB-INF/lib folder. Then, I added these jars into my build path using: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> Select the jars from the WEB-INF/lib folder.